# How to deserialize a json object into rust understandable code using enums?

Tags: parsing, rust, serialization, enums, serde

I need to deserialize ( and later on serialize ) a piece of data that has this type of a structure :

```
{
  "type": "TypeApplication",
  "val": {
    "con": {
      "type": "TypeConstructor",
      "val": [
        "Builtin",
        "Record"
      ]
    },
    "arg": {
      "type": "RowCons",
      "val": {
        "label": "953e3dd6-826e-1985-cb99-fd4ed4da754e",
        "type": {
          "type": "TypeApplication",
          "val": {
            "con": {
              "type": "TypeConstructor",
              "val": [
                "Builtin",
                "List"
              ]
            },
            "arg": {
              "type": "Element",
              "meta": {
                "multiLine": true
              }
            }
          },
          "system": {
            "label": "nullam-senectus-port - Text",
            "isBindable": true,
            "defaultValue": [
              {
                "id": "4a05486f-f24d-45f8-ae13-ab05f824d74d",
                "type": "String",
                "pluginType": "Basic",
                "data": {
                  "value": "Nullam senectus porttitor in eget. Eget rutrum leo interdum."
                },
                "children": [],
                "text": true
              }
            ],
            "isUnlinked": false,
            "isDefault": false
          }
        },
        "tail": {
          "type": "RowCons",
          "val": {
            "label": "94f603df-d585-b45a-4252-9ec77cf5b13c",
            "type": {
              "type": "TypeApplication",
              "val": {
                "con": {
                  "type": "TypeConstructor",
                  "val": [
                    "Builtin",
                    "List"
                  ]
                },
                "arg": {
                  "type": "Element",
                  "meta": {
                    "multiLine": true
                  }
                }
              },
              "system": {
                "label": "best-services - Text",
                "isBindable": true,
                "defaultValue": [
                  {
                    "id": "6265ca45-3f69-4844-97e2-c05bbfb9fee5",
                    "type": "String",
                    "pluginType": "Basic",
                    "data": {
                      "value": "Best Services"
                    },
                    "children": [],
                    "text": true
                  }
                ]
              }
            },
            "tail": {
              "type": "RowEmpty"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I do not know what this data exactly is, but I know this is trying to represent a function/element that takes in values and defaults for those values as parameters/properties.

I want to deserialize it using **serde** and consequently serialize it too.
I have so far been able to write something that sort of works but not really :

```
#[skip_serializing_none]
#[derive(Deserialize, Serialize, Debug, Clone)]
#[serde(tag = "type", content = "val")]
pub enum WebflowPropDataType {
    TypeApplication {
        con: Box<WebflowPropDataType>, // Normally Passes the Type Constructor
        arg: Box<WebflowPropDataType>, // Normally Passes the Row Constructor
    },
    TypeConstructor(Vec<String>), // Stores Value of TypeConstructor
    RowCons {
        label: String, // Stores the label of the Row
        #[serde(rename = "type")]
        row_con_type: Box<WebflowPropDataType>, // Stores the type of the Row
        tail: Box<WebflowPropDataType>,
    },
    RowEmpty, // For Ending the recursive usage of rowConstructor
}

#[skip_serializing_none]
#[derive(Deserialize, Serialize, Debug, Clone)]
pub struct WebflowRowConDataType {
    #[serde(rename = "type")]
    val_type: String, // TypeApplication
    val: Box<WebflowPropDataType>,
}
```

This works for a structure like this :

```
{
    "type": "TypeApplication",
    "val":{
        "con": {
            "type": "TypeConstructor",
            "val": []
          },       
        "arg": {
            "type": "RowEmpty"
        }
    }
}
```

but would fail if I try to work with initial example. I know this may be due to the lack of a proper `arg` type or maybe even the `TypeApplication` Enum hand is malformed.

I do see that a adjancent typing solution would be enough for most of the times but there are cases as seen in the example structure that there is a third value called `system` and I am unable to determine what type of approach would help me achieve this type of outcome.

How should I approach this problem in order to generate this type of code.

I am not asking anyone to write me a solution but to give me suggestion as to what my approach should be? Whether you'd know what type of data this is/how to generated this , or even if there are some other library I should look into to manipulate this type of data or maybe look at other approaches.

**PS** : - My end goal is to be able to generate / serialize this type of JSON code from already contained knowledge of properties and default values of a function/object.

Comment: "sort of works but not really" - is what ways does it accomplish what you want or achieves it sub-optimally?

Comment: nit: `#[skip_serializing_none]` does nothing here

Comment: @PitaJ updated the question to show examples , and issues. Also kept `#[skip_serializing_none]` because this is my default macro template for the data structures. You are right , so I will be removing it! Thanks!

Comment: @Stargateur sorry if my question seemed it was seeking for a complete solution! I updated the question to better reflect what I actually require, which is more like a suggestion/ sharing of knowledge if anyone has about this data structure that I have stumbled across .

Comment: Do you have power over the JSON data structure or is it fixed?

Comment: PitaJ's first comment still stands though - please provide the code you tested (including a `main` and `use` statements and everything, including the output/behaviour your code gives, and what bothers you about that output. It's called a [MRE]. Only like that can we guide you towards your goal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are my recommendations:

1. Use just `#[serde(tag = "type")]` instead of `#[serde(tag = "type", content = "val")]`. You will have to handle `val` manually (extracting the current enum members into separate structs), but this allows you to also handle `TypeApplication.system` and `Element.meta`.

   This also has the small benefit of reducing the amount of `Box`es involved.
2. Consider whether all of the different cases in `WebflowPropDataType` can actually occur everywhere it's used. If not (maybe `Element` can only happen under `TypeApplication.val.arg`), then you may want to split the enum into multiple so that this is reflected in the type system.

---

Example for #1:

```rust
use serde::{Serialize, Deserialize};

#[derive(Deserialize, Serialize, Debug, Clone)]
pub struct TypeApplicationVal {
    con: WebflowPropDataType, // Normally Passes the Type Constructor
    arg: WebflowPropDataType, // Normally Passes the Row Constructor
}

// #[skip_serializing_none]
#[derive(Deserialize, Serialize, Debug, Clone)]
pub struct TypeApplicationSystem {
    label: String,
    #[serde(rename = "isBindable")]
    is_bindable: bool,

    // TODO: defaultValue

    #[serde(rename = "isUnlinked")]
    #[serde(skip_serializing_if = "Option::is_none")]
    is_unlinked: Option<bool>,
    #[serde(rename = "isDefault")]
    #[serde(skip_serializing_if = "Option::is_none")]
    is_default: Option<bool>,
}

#[derive(Deserialize, Serialize, Debug, Clone)]
pub struct RowConsVal {
    label: String, // Stores the label of the Row
    #[serde(rename = "type")]
    typ: WebflowPropDataType, // Stores the type of the Row
    tail: WebflowPropDataType,
}

#[derive(Deserialize, Serialize, Debug, Clone)]
pub struct ElementMeta {
    #[serde(rename = "multiLine")]
    multi_line: bool,
}

#[derive(Deserialize, Serialize, Debug, Clone)]
#[serde(tag = "type")]
pub enum WebflowPropDataType {
    TypeApplication {
        val: Box<TypeApplicationVal>,
        #[serde(skip_serializing_if = "Option::is_none")]
        system: Option<TypeApplicationSystem>,
    },
    TypeConstructor {
        val: Vec<String> // Stores Value of TypeConstructor
    },
    RowCons {
        val: Box<RowConsVal>,
    },
    Element {
        meta: ElementMeta,
    },
    RowEmpty, // For Ending the recursive usage of rowConstructor
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=129364f81b906b92fb535ca958d57487)

Comment: This seems like a great way of doing it! I will try to test it out! Thanks for your time!